# When would this Koajs error happen

Tags: koa, koa2

I'm trying to get my head around Koa and I am making small progress. At the moment I think I understand this code

```
import Koa from 'koa';
import router from './router';

const app = new Koa();

app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  try {
    await next();
  } catch (err) {
    ctx.body = { message: err.message };
    ctx.status = err.status || 500;
  }
});
app.use(router.routes());
app.listen(3000);

export default app;
```

Instead of having a callback to handle the error, we go upstream to that catch. But I would like to make the above error execute.

How can I simulate an error

Answer (score 0):

If you have an unhandled error in your upstream code, THEN this error here would fire.

Answer (score 0):

To simulate an error do :

```
throw new Error('error message')
```